# Push new object at specific index using immutability helper

Tags: reactjs, react-native, immutability-helper

I have tried to do this:

```
 const rowObj = {key: value};
    const rowIndex = 2;

    this.setState({ 
          data: update(this.state.data, 
              { [rowIndex] : { $push : [rowObj] } }
          ) 
    })
```

But, It throw error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: update(): expected target of $push to be an array; got undefined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try like this**

```
const rowArray = [{key: value},{key: value},{key: value}];
const obj = {key: value}
const rowIndex = 2;
rowArray.splice(rowIndex, 0, obj);
this.setState({ data: update(this.state.data,{rowArray : {$set : rowArray}} ) });
```

Comment: brilliant bro.. thats exactly what i m looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to push to an array i.e data, you would not want to specify the index and write it like

```
const rowObj = {key: value};

this.setState({ 
      data: update(this.state.data, 
           { $push : [rowObj] } 
      ) 
})
```

or else if you want to set a value to a particular index in the array, you should use `$set`

```
const rowObj = {key: value};
const rowIndex = 2;

this.setState({ 
      data: update(this.state.data, 
          { [rowIndex] : { $set : rowObj } }
      ) 
})
```

Comment: but in my case i need to insert new row on particular index.. i cant use $set.. is it possible with push?

Comment: any other option without using looping? bcz my row data length is about 5000+

Comment: Since this.state.data[rowIndex] is undefined and not an arrary before you push, it will give you an error and why can't you use set

Comment: [{id: 1, rowId: "rw153431859379599d449", sequence: 1, cl1534318588226572647: "asd", cl15343185882290af581: "test"},
{id: 2, rowId: "rw1534318593795aea780", sequence: 2, cl1534318588226572647: null, cl15343185882290af581: null},
{id: 16, rowId: "rw1534396933085ae919c", sequence: 3, cl1534318588226572647: null, cl15343185882290af581: null}]

Comment: @SagarChavada, its visible from your sample data that this.state.data[rowIndex] is not an array, but an object and push property is not supported on object, you should instead use $set or $merge if you want to merge the properties

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942555/2956628) here's a version that uses immutability helper itself

```
const rowArray = [{
  key: value
}, {
  key: value
}, {
  key: value
}];
const obj = {
  key: value
}
const rowIndex = 2;
this.setState({
  data: update(this.state.data, {
    rowArray: {
      $splice: [
        [rowIndex, 0, obj]
      ]
    }
  })
});
```